# Sorting by addOrderRule and adjusting ticks

Tags: dimple.js

I am trying to make a horizontal bar chart in dimple that will (1) sort descending values and (2) have tick marks set to ".2f" (2 decimal places) so tooltips also have 2 decimal places.

The code below sorts by default ascending values even after I set .addOrderRule to true and does not even draw the chart when I specify a .tickFormat

What am I doing wrong?  Seems so simple, but I've been racking my brain!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var margin = 75,
        width = 1000 - margin,
        height = 500 - margin;

    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin)
        .attr("height", height + margin);

    d3.csv("flower-prices.csv", function (data) {

      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
      myChart.setBounds(150, 30, 700, 350);

      var x = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "avgprice");
      x.tickFormat(".2f");

      var y = myChart.addCategoryAxis("y", "strain");

      var series = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
      series.addOrderRule("avgprice", true);

      myChart.draw();

    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

axis.tickFormat is correct but it needs to be set as a member property, rather than using the function notation.  Therefore you just need to use:

```
x.tickFormat = ".2f";
```

The order rule needs to be applied to the axis rather than the series (a series order rule affects stack order in a bar, which is not relevant here).  Also descending/ascending is based on zero rather than the top so (perhaps a little counter-intuitively) the default is descending and I guess here you want ascending so it should be:

```
y.addOrderRule("avgprice", false);
```

Comment: Thank you John!  That was it.  The first point I think was a result of "the stupid hour" haha.  I understand the second point now.  Thank you for clarifying ordering axis vs measures.